# OpenCV cv::Mat 'ones' for multi-channel matrix?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing, opencv, matrix

When working with 1-channel (e.g. `CV_8UC1`) Mat objects in OpenCV, this creates a Mat of all ones: `cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::ones(x,y,CV_8UC1)`.

However, when I use 3-channel images (e.g. `CV_8UC3`), things get a little more complicated. Doing `cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::ones(x,y,CV_8UC3)` puts *ones* into channel 0, but channels 1 and 2 contain *zeros*. **So, how do I use `cv::Mat::ones()` for multi-channel images?**

Here's some code that might help you to see what I mean:

```
void testOnes() {
 int x=2; int y=2; //arbitrary

 // 1 channel
 cv::Mat img_C1 = cv::Mat::ones(x,y,CV_8UC1);
 uchar px1 = img_C1.at<uchar>(0,0); //not sure of correct data type for px in 1-channel img
 printf("px of 1-channel img: %d \n", (int)px1); //prints 1

 // 3 channels
 cv::Mat img_C3 = cv::Mat::ones(x,y,CV_8UC3); //note 8UC3 instead of 8UC1
 cv::Vec3b px3 = img_C3.at<cv::Vec3b>(0,0);
 printf("px of 3-channel img: %d %d %d \n", (int)px3[0], (int)px3[1], (int)px3[2]); //prints 1 0 0
}
```

So, I would have expected to see this printout: `px of 3-channel img: 1 1 1`, but instead I see this: `px of 3-channel img: 1 0 0`.

P.S. I did a lot of searching before posting this. I wasn't able to resolve this by searching SO for "[opencv] Mat::ones" or "[opencv] +mat +ones".

Comment: Sidenote: I'm not sure if I should use `uchar` in place of `cv::Vec3b` for a 1-channel image pixel. OpenCV offers a lot of 2-, 3-, and 4-item vector classes, but no analogy for a singleton. (Search for `Vec3b` on this page: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#vec)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't use OpenCV, but I believe I know what's going on here.  You define a data-type, but you are requesting the value '1' for that.  The `Mat` class appears not to pay attention to the fact that you have a multi-channel datatype, so it simply casts '1' as a 3-byte unsigned char.

So instead of using the `ones` function, just use the scalar constructor:

```
cv::Mat img_C3( x, y, CV_8UC3, CV_RGB(1,1,1) );
```

Comment: I just tried out your solution. `cv::Mat img_C3 = cv::Mat::ones(x,y,CV_8UC3) * CV_RGB(1,1,1);` doesn't compile, because there isn't an overloaded operator `*` for the `cv::Mat` type. `cv::Mat img_C3( x,y,CV_8UC3,CV_RGB(1,1,1) );` compiles, but it defines a pixel's channels as `1 0 0`, just like in the `ones` example from my question. I'm digging into your answer more deeply now.

Comment: Oh, wait, `cv::Mat img_C3( x,y,CV_8UC3,CV_RGB(1,1,1) );` DOES work properly!

Comment: I would expect the first solution to work, based on where I found it (http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/basic_structures.html#cv-mat-ones), but perhaps it doesn't work with the return type for `CV_RGB`.  I originally wrote 0x10101 before stumbling across that macro.  Try that, and if it works I'll adjust your proposed edits.

Comment: When I do this: `cv::Mat img_C3 = cv::Mat::ones(x,y,CV_8UC3) * CV_RGB(1,1,1);`, the code prints `px of 3-channel img: 255 0 0`. Part of the problem is that, if we start with pixels of value {1,0,0}, multiplying the image by a number gives us {n,0,0}. However, I was wrong about the `*` operator not being overloaded--it clearly works when multiplying by a primitive data type. Thanks for following up and spending so much time on this. :)

Comment: Hmmm, that's strange.  In that case, it looks like it's doing individual channel multiplications and clamping the result.  Anyway, that `ones` method is nowhere near as good as just using a scalar constructor.  So it's win-win for you =)

Comment: Definitely! I'e accepted/upvoted your answer, but we should probably make it clear (for future readers' sake) that your second answer is the one to use. Any chance you could point this out in your answer (or authorize the revisions that I proposed)?

Comment: No worries.  For some reason, your edit didn't show up for me again.  Anyway, I just removed the other option.  It was silly anyway.  Also, I subsequently read that using the `*` operator doesn't actually multiply on the spot.  It stores a scaling factor for later.  Sounds dodgey to me.

Answer (score 2):

You can also initialize like this:

```
Mat img;

/// Lots of stuff here ...

// Need to initialize again for some reason:
img = Mat::Mat(Size(width, height), CV_8UC3, CV_RGB(255,255,255));
```